# js почему массив авто сортируется

Tags: javascript, массивы

нужен такой вложенный массив

```js
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1],
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
[8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
[9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

let arr=[];
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr[0]=a;
for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    a.push(a.shift());
    arr[i]=a;
    console.log(arr[i]) //1
}

console.log(arr); //2
```

в первом выводе получается правильно, а во втором так:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

почему? есть автосортировка массива?

Comment: изменил ваш код на сниппет, и что-то во втором месте выводится не то, что вы указали. И заметьте, есть разница. в первом случае вы выводите `arr[i]` то есть только текущую строку, а во втором массив целиком. Если в первом вы выведите не только текущую, но и предыдущую, например, то удивительным образом окажется, что она такая же как и текущая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас создается один массив из 10 элементов. На каждой итерации цикла вы переставляете в нем первый элемент в конец и вставляете ссылку на этот массив в `arr`. Соответственно в итоге вы получаете `arr` содержащий 10 ссылок на один и тот же массив.

Comment: решение `arr[i]=[...a];`